# I cant find Telerik.Windows.Controls.Media to use Telerik RadWebCam

Tags: wpf, telerik, webcam

In my WPF application I need to use `Telerik RadWebCam`, I'm trying to follow this [Documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radwebcam/getting-started) but I cant find the following assemblies:

- Telerik.Windows.Controls.Media
- Telerik.Windows.MediaFoundation

My Telerik version is Q1 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Telerik `RadWebCam` for WPF is available since

- [UI for WPF R2 2019](https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/wpf/release-history/ui-for-wpf-r2-2019) as **beta** release
- [UI for WPF R3 2019](https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/wpf/release-history/ui-for-wpf-r3-2019) as official release

So it is not included in the older Q1 2016 release.